# Unable to create pyspark session

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to create a pyspark session and I am getting a directory error. Can someone please advise on how to solve this issue? Thank you@[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpE3q.png)

I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post all code and error messages as plain text.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Here is the code.                                                          
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DataFrameBasics").getOrCreate()

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Seems that you didn't configure the spark correctly, the spark-submit binary couldn't be found. I think you need to configure the path in the IDE you were using.

Comment: Thank you Wenyi Xu. How do I configure the path in IDE on mac?